# How do you configure TortoiseSVN to use Visual Studio 2012 for diffing?

Tags: svn, visual-studio-2012, tortoisesvn, diff

I want to use the new Visual Studio diffing tool for diffing changes via TortoiseSVN. What do I type in the external tool command line box?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `vsDiffMerge.exe` to do this.

## Visual Studio 2012

Diff:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe" /t %base %mine %bname %yname
```

Merge:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\vsDiffMerge.exe" /m %theirs %mine %base %merged
```

## Visual Studio 2013 & 2014

Just identify the version number and replace the `12.0` in the above commands with the want you want. (Tested with 2015, `14.0`.)

## Visual Studio 2017

Diff:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe" /t %base %mine %bname %yname
```

Merge:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\vsDiffMerge.exe" /m %theirs %mine %base %merged
```

## References

#### vsDiffMerge.exe usage

See [here](http://roadtoalm.com/2013/10/22/use-visual-studio-as-your-diff-and-merging-tool-for-local-files/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17557108/238753).

#### TortoiseSVN command substitution

- [TortoiseSVN diff command substitutions](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-Diff)
- [TortoiseSVN merge command substitutions](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-Merge)

Comment: Changed the answer to this one, since it does both, it seems a better answer now. Please comment if you disagree.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe -diff %base %mine
```

Taken from the TortoiseSVN manual, which shows the %paramNames around halfway down the page.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-settings.html#tsvn-dug-settings-progs